# Slash commands in Circuit

Tags: circuit-sdk

I'm creating a bot using Circuit JS SDK. And I want that users could interact with bot by sending slash commands (eg. "/help"). 
Does Circuit supports auto-sending command by clicking on command (like Telegram does)? And if it's not, is there something that I can use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Circuit JS SDK does not support slash commands, maybe in the future. But you can use the `mention` event or the `itemAdded` event and parse the content yourself.

Some apps don't want to use slash commands but instead pass the text into an NLP/AI service such as DialogFlow when the bot is being mentioned. Others use custom commands such as `stream rtsp://`, or

Here are a few examples:
- listen for mention event with custom command:https://github.com/circuit/drone-bot/blob/master/index.js#L76 or https://github.com/circuit/trivia-quiz/blob/master/app.js#L561
- listen for addItem event and pass content to NLP: https://github.com/circuit/support-bot/blob/master/server.js#L68